# Vertical progress bar

Tags: c#, progress-bar

VS 2005 SP3

I have worked with the progress bar many times.

However, I need to have one that is vertical. However, I can't find any property that will rotate it.

Is the progress bar always in a horizontal position and cannot be changed.

Many thanks,

Comment: Hmm, vertical progress bar. Interesting concept. While I have no specific help, perhaps you can place it on a panel/'thing' that is rotatable?

Comment: Turn your monitor 90 degrees? (I kid, I kid -- I need to go to bed).

Comment: It would be simple in WPF, but I guess that's not much help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar { 
   protected override CreateParams CreateParams { 
    get { 
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; 
      cp.Style |= 0x04; 
      return cp; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

From: [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60b2493d-c8ff-495d-b845-d114fe456f54)

Comment: For those wondering, 0x04 is the PBS_VERTICAL constant, defined in the commctrl.h header file in the Windows SDK.