# create vertical progress bar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar, orientation

I am trying to find a way to create a vertical progress bar in a VB.NET Windows application. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285966/vertical-progress-bar), but it's in C# and thus not all that much help to me. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doesn't the C# answer help you? I ran it through [a code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) and it worked straight away:

```
Public Class VerticalProgressBar
    Inherits ProgressBar
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.Style = cp.Style Or &H4
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

**Edit**
Although you should really define a public constant for the (PBS_VERTICAL) style value (&H4), rather than using a magic number in code like that.

Comment: I'm thinking @Matt didn't know about converters and didn't know how to convert it manually.

Comment: @druciferre Nope, had no idea. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Matt: In case you missed the edit, I've linked to the code converter I used.